# ApplicationDbContext for static classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what I've got:

```
//PUT: api/teams/id/member/id
[Route ("api/Detail/detial_id/Option/option_id")]
public IHttpActionResult PutTeams(int team_id, int member_id)
{
   var team = db.Teams.Find(team_id);
   var member= db.Members.Find(member_id);
}
```

I can't write this piece of code:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<cb_api.Models.Member> Teams{ get; set; }
```

in context.cs since Member is  a static class but I need it in order to used in PutTeam.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity classes cannot be a static class. These classes should be instantiable. Why do you want it to be a static class?. The teams are stored in the database and whenever you want to fetch it from the database, you need DBSet properties having Entity types passed. So the Teams property with Member class type cannot be a static class.

**To convert them to JSON**
Create a Static class called GenericHelper.cs

```
public static class GenericHelper
{
    public static string ToJson(this IList<Member> teams)
    {
         //convert these objects and return json string using JSONConvert.SerializeObject
    }
}
```

Comment: It's static because I used an extended method in it, ToJson()

Comment: For that, there are other options I will answer it.

Comment: @Mars check the updated answer and also update your question